# Can I ‘upgrade’ my Animal Companion with the Giant or Advanced Creature templates instead?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, animal-companions, character-templates

I am going to play a druid in Pathfinder and I want to take a wolf as my companion. Is it possible to advance this wolf (or claim a new wolf) with the giant template?

I am aware that at level 7 it would be Large as well, but I am trying to give the wolf the template instead of leveling it the next time we get enough XP to level up. Because the giant template has a CR+1 I think adding it to my beloved companion instead of the bonus he would gain with his next level on the Animal Companion Table is not against the rules.

It would be a Wolf with CR+1 at my Character Level − 1.

Am I right?

Or, if the advancement of my actual companion is not going to work, is there a possibility to claim a new wolf with the Giant Template as my new companion after releasing my beloved follower?

We are just playing with the Pathfinder Core Rule Book, the Advanced Player's Guide, the Bestiary, and the GM book; if the rules for this question are anywhere else I don't know other sourcebooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no mention of the [animal companion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions) rules in the [rules for the simple template giant](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/monsterAdvancement.html#giant-creature) and vice versa; the concepts simply don't interact. 
And in most *Pathfinder* campaigns the GM—not the players—determine which rules are used and which aren't. This means that while *you* may think it's totally legit to apply the [simple template giant](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions) to your druid's [wolf](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/wolf) [animal companion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions), it's *not* legit unless permission to do so is granted by the GM.

However, I can totally understand *wanting* a 2nd-level druid to have as an animal companion a giant wolf. Because that's awesome. But there's no way for that to happen that I'm aware of that doesn't involve convincing the GM to change the rules. A Large wolf will happen automatically at level 7, and until then, you stick it out with a Medium wolf. Maybe buy a [*dire collar*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/dire-collar) for your wolf in the meantime?

(A player's interaction with the simple template giant is rare, but some [druids](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid) do—specifically, the totemic summons ability of the [ape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo---druid-archetypes/ape-shaman), [bat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo---druid-archetypes/bat-shaman), [bear](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo---druid-archetypes/bear-shaman), [boar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo---druid-archetypes/boar-shaman), and [dragon shamans](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo---druid-archetypes/dragon-shaman). But that's only for summoning not animal companions and still doesn't affect, for example, the [wolf shaman](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo---druid-archetypes/wolf-shaman).)

Comment: The wolf shamen says "This ability otherwise functions as the bear shaman ability." Doesnt that mean / suggest they can also apply the templates to their summons? This still would not affect their animal companion.

Comment: @Duncan Maybe? The wolf shaman totemic summons could've used another editorial pass. That is, technically, the wolf shaman summons wolves and bears more quickly, but can only apply the templates to bears. That's dumb, obviously, and presumably unintended, so I just assumed in my answer the most conservative house rule.

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan With RAW you are right. The spelling in the description is as you say but i guess the meaning and therefore the right interpretation of this section is to change the wording 'bear' in 'wolf' or what shaman you are looking for. Otherwise the giant collar seems to fit my needs and i will give it a try if my DM will give me a chance to purchase it.