# Can you choose to add a template to a druid's animal companion instead of adding a hit die?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, druid, animal-companions, character-templates

One of my fellow players posed a scenario that I can't really find a satisfactory answer to. A level 10 character has the Wild Cohort feat and can have an animal companion as a level 7 druid. Since he can have an animal companion with 7 hit dice, can he choose to add a template instead of adding a hit die to avoid the maximum number of hit die his companion can have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I ‘upgrade’ my Animal Companion with the Giant or Advanced Creature templates instead?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77022/can-i-upgrade-my-animal-companion-with-the-giant-or-advanced-creature-template)

Comment: @TuggyNE Close, but that one's for PF instead of 3.5e. I almost VtC'd before I caught that detail at the last minute.

Comment: Can you source the version of the feat Wild Cohort that you're using in your game? I'm concerned that it isn't the feat [Wild Cohort](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/re/20031118a) with which I'm most familiar as that feat neither measures a wild cohort's value in Hit Dice nor caps the wild cohort's Hit Dice.

Comment: In D&D 3.0e, a druid's animal companion did have a hit die cap.  @SevenSidedDie, are you sure you were correct in adding the dnd-3.5e tag, rather than a 3.0e tag?

Comment: @DanB [Yep.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/80585/1)

Comment: I must have misread.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: I did see that, but as far as I know the distinction is not meaningful in this case; the rules are sufficiently similar that closing as a dupe is the correct way to say "yes, these work the same way".

Comment: @TuggyNE We've had this come up before and it's less tangled to just treat them as separate. The alternative means dealing with errors in VtCs, arguments about degree of rule similarity, and problems when errata or Voice of Designer makes them no longer the same. Easier and cleaner just to let them be independent games with independent questions from the outset.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## The feat [Wild Cohort](https://web.archive.org/web/20210217062407/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/re/20031118a) provides no option for the wild cohort to have a template

The benefit of the feat [Wild Cohort](https://web.archive.org/web/20210217062407/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/re/20031118a) says, in part, that

> You gain an animal cohort.... Provided the DM gives her approval, at 1st level you can choose from a badger, camel, dire rat, dog, riding dog, eagle, hawk, horse (light or heavy), owl, pony, snake (Small or Medium viper), or wolf. Like a druid, you can choose more powerful animals as you increase in level. These alternative animal cohorts work like the alternative animal companions available to a druid, but they are available as cohorts later than they are available as animal companions. When selecting an alternative animal cohort, use the list of alternative animal companions on page 36 of the *Player’s Handbook*, but treat yourself as a druid three levels lower than your character level....

Thus the wild cohort is much like an [animal companion](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#animalCompanion) that, likewise, is acquired without templates. Further, the wild cohort's number of Hit Dice isn't specified; instead, the creature with the feat Wild Cohort has an ersatz effective druid level, which doesn't translate easily or directly into the wild cohort's Hit Dice or Challenge Rating. Finally, an *animal* is specified throughout the feat's description; a template that changes the wild cohort into something *other* than an animal renders the cohort invalid.

#### ...But, hey, it's a game

If everyone agrees that instead of a regular ol' badger that a half-celestial half-dragon badger is somehow acceptable (like, maybe the guy with the feat Wild Cohort is a monk or something), that's great, and no one can stop you. Have fun.

Comment: So said player could not have a wolf with a ghost template, going off RAW.

Comment: @SiamSid  According to RAW, absolutely not. A creature with the feat Wild Cohort can't *via* that feat gain, for example, a [ghost](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/ghost.htm) [dog](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dog.htm).